# Why is the "SecStaticCodeCheckValidity" method drilling my memory?

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, codesign

I have an application that verifies code signatures. I am using SecStaticCodeCheckValidity to check if a signature is valid. Before I call the method I have a relatively small memory footprint, but after the method finishes execution my memory footprint is almost doubled and I don't know where exactly this happens.

```
    OSStatus errorCode=SecStaticCodeCheckValidity(_codeReference, kSecCSConsiderExpiration,NULL);
    CFRelease(_codeReference);
    switch(errorCode)
    {
            case errSecInvalidRoot:validity=INVALID;
                break;
            case errSecCRLNotValidYet:validity=NOT_VALID_YET;
                break;
            case errSecCertificateRevoked:validity=REVOKED;
                break;
            case errSecCertificateExpired:validity=EXPIRED;
                break;
            case errSecSuccess:_signatureValidity=VALID;
                break;
            default: validity=BROKEN;
                break;
    }
```

Now what exactly am I supposed to release when I have already released the "`_codeReference`" ?

**UPDATE:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    SecStaticCodeRef codeRef;
    CFURLRef appURL=CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("/Applications/Xcode.app"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, YES);
    SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(appURL, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &codeRef);
    CFRelease(appURL);
    CFDictionaryRef signDic;
    SecCodeCopySigningInformation(codeRef, kSecCSSigningInformation, &signDic);
    if(!CFDictionaryContainsKey(signDic,kSecCodeInfoIdentifier))
    {
        NSLog(@"Bundle not signed....");
        return 0;
    }
    CFRelease(signDic);
    //Verify signature
    OSStatus code=SecStaticCodeCheckValidity(codeRef, kSecCSConsiderExpiration, NULL);
    CFRelease(codeRef);
    NSString*output;
    switch(code)
    {
        case errSecInvalidRoot:output=@"INVALID";
            break;
        case errSecCRLNotValidYet:output=@"NOT_VALID_YET";
            break;
        case errSecCertificateRevoked:output=@"REVOKED";
            break;
        case errSecCertificateExpired:output=@"EXPIRED";
            break;
        case errSecSuccess:output=@"VALID";
            break;
        default: output=@"BROKEN";
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",output);
    return 0;
}
```

I have updated my SampleApplication and monitored the app in Instruments.
[image]
This means that I am not correctly releasing memory in my code.

Comment: How do you know that is what is actually leaking?

Comment: I have been monitoring the memory with the Activity Monitor and Xcode. In Xcode I have been using the memory graph for debugging. I just thought that I could perform the verification over the shell with codesign, but unfortunately codesign seems to have the same problem.

Comment: `codesign` isn't continually running though; it runs and then exits. There's nothing in your code above though that should be leaking. If you have debug logs of the behavior then I recommend you post them with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after I have rewritten my code to use ARC all memory issues are gone. So it was actually my fault that objects were not properly released.